# What is the maximal value of $|A\cup B|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For $A$ and $B$ sets that is different from null,

$4. |A-B| = 3 . |A' \cap B|$

$3. |A| - |B| = 20$

What is the maximal value of $|A\cup B|$?

It seems so confused right now. Can you take a look?

Comment: @AirConditioner Why? Isn't it correct?

Comment: @AirConditioner I think that's correct. However I'm stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $|A\setminus B|=x$, $|A\cap B|=y$ and $|B\setminus A|=z.$

Thus, $$4x=3z$$ and
$$3(x+y)-(y+z)=20,$$ which gives
$$x=12-\frac{6}{5}y,$$ $$z=16-\frac{8}{5}y$$ and
$$|A\cup B|=x+y+z=28-\frac{9}{5}y\leq28.$$
The equality occurs for $|A\cap B|=0.$

Comment: Great answer! Got it ;)

Comment: Can you put your answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2508809 for undeletion?  "You know who" put it for deletion as a retaliation in something you did not participate.  I find it utterly unfair and petty.  If you can (but I don't know if you could, since it is your answer), and since you have sufficient reputation to put your answer for undeletion, I will cast a vote for it to be undeleted.